# Are there more advantages to returning an empty string or null value?

Tags: php, return-value, return-type

If I were writing the below method (for example) is it considered good practice to either:

A: return an empty string if the document didn't exist?

B: return a `null` value?

Having done a lot of Java, and methods in Java requiring a return type, I'm under the impression it is best practice to return a consistent type, is this also the case in PHP or is it better to return a `null` value instead?

```
DocumentClass
{
    public function getDir($documentId)
    {
        /* Code to get location of document  */
        return (file_exists($document) ? $document : '');
    }
}

if (!empty($documentClass->getDir(5))
{
    /* Do this */
}
```

If it is better to return a `null` value, can you explain why?

Comment: I prefer to return booleans wherever possible.

Comment: This function will return `FALSE` for to non-existing files.

Comment: @diEcho Are you sure, I've just tested the above and it does indeed return a string value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### PHP convention

Return boolean `FALSE`.

#### OOP approch

Throw an exception. Also you should use a method `dir_exitsts` (or any other name you like) that only returns boolean (true of false). And use it before calling `getDir`

There really no specific rule for this. Its completely up to you.

I follow  *PHP way* which is returning `false`.

Comment: +1. I'm coming from java and I would not like to return NULL from a method called getDir() since it may cause a NPE later on. Instead add a method like dirExists($id) and then throw exception if trying to load a dir that doesn't exist.

Comment: @tfont you meant the *exception* method?

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer this borderline opinion-based question with as little opinion as possible.

From PHP7.1, "[nullable return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)" were available.

There is no such thing as "falsible return types" or "empty string return types".

From PHP8, the "[null-safe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403)" became available.

If I am creating a function (or method) that returns a boolean, then it will have a function name that also indicates that boolean return value should be expected (e.g. something starting with `is`, `was`, `has`, etc) and the calling code can always safely use `===` to check its value if desired.  I will not optionally return `null` from these functions.  If there is any reason to deviate from the boolean type result, then I'll be throwing an exception.

When a function is going to return an array, I do not optionally return `null` either -- if anything other than an array is appropriate, again I'll throw an exception.  An empty array is a falsey value, so I  don't need `null` to serve this purpose.

As for string and object type returns, I am definitely in favor of optionally using nulls.  Having the distinction between a zero-length string and a null can be very useful.  I also prefer for a `null` over an empty object because unlike an empty array, an [empty object is truthy](https://3v4l.org/Sscjn).

From PHP7, the "[null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)" became available. This allows very succinct syntax for falling back to a default value.

All of these contributions to the language steer PHP developers to gravitate to nulls for convenience.

Granted, "[mixed return types](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/mixed-type#:%7E:text=mixed%20is%20a%20pseudo%20type,%2C%20callable%20%2C%20and%20even%20resource%20.)" became available in PHP8, but this only opens up an already loose/forgiving system.  I am more often trying find ways to tighten my projects so that they are less prone to breakage.

Comment: George Peter Banyard also indicates that NULL is encouraged in the "true return type" RFC.

See: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/true-type
_"While we nowadays encourage the use of null over false as an error or absence return value, for historical reasons many internal functions continue to use false instead."_

Answer (score 2):

What would you do with this returned value? Should this signal a logical error, illegal input - or just some edge case?

In both 'error' cases I'd stick with exceptions instead of some fringe return values - especially because PHP is weakly-typed language, and it's way too easy to mix NULL and '' in some (stupidly) written `==` expression.

For edge cases perhaps I'd stick with `FALSE` as a value to return. It's, to my mind, a bit broken approach (check this link for the [truly maddening example](http://php.net/function.array-search#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues)), but at least it's a common idiom in PHP.

Comment: It's more of an edge case. Do you have any links or references to returning FALSE in an instance like this being a common idiom that I could look into? Thanks.

Comment: Check PHP [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), for example: most of them (from `strpos/strstr` and its minions right to `explode`) return `FALSE` if something went wrong (though the _wrongness_ vastly differs). The same approach is used by many [filesystem functions](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) as well.

Comment: In fact, the phrase `returns FALSE on failure` is quite... popular in php.net documentation section: here's [proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22returns+FALSE+on+failure%22+site:php.net). ) But even this behavior can be inconsistent, such as with [array_search function](http://ua.php.net/function.array-search#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues). Oh my.

Answer (score 2):

There are two popular return values for this: `false` or `null`

The internal functions of PHP seem to favour `false` for arbitrary reasons, but I personally prefer `null` because it's a better candidate to represent `undefined`.

Side note: testing for false (`false` === $x) is slightly more typing than `is_null($x)` :)

However, in many cases, the code that receives this return value can't do anything meaningful with it; this is when you can throw exceptions to skip that code segment, just like in Java; it's a convenient flow control mechanism for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

[`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) return **FALSE** for to non-existing files.

so you can change your condition with this way

```
if (false ! == $documentClass->getDir(5))
{
    /* Do this */
}
```

alternative :  **[`is_readable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)**

> this returns **TRUE** if the file or directory specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the questoin seems to be about OOP, then take note that you can also decide to create yourself a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), this wikipedia page on that pattern contains a "Description", which coincidentally uses a directory lister as an example, as it happens, guys and gals ...